# HTTPS requests in Restlet Java framework

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restlet

I'm very new to the restlet framework and pretty much webservices in general. I'm managing fine to send requests to 'HTTP' resources but as soon as I try and hit 'HTTPS' resources with my code I get the following error:

> No available client connector supports the required protocols: 'HTTPS' . Please add the JAR of a matching connector to your classpath.

So this could simply be solved by adding a certain .jar to my project but I don't know which one. Or.. it could be a bit more complicated than that. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

PS - Using Restlet 2.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> In addition to the standard Restlet jar files, you also need to
>   reference jar files for HTTPS. The 'Simple' HTTPS connector uses these
>   jar files:
>
> lib/com.noelios.restlet.ext.simple_3.1.jar
>
> lib/org.simpleframework_3.1/org.simpleframework.jar
>
> lib/com.noelios.restlet.ext.ssl.jar
>
> lib/org.jsslutils_0.5/org.jsslutils.jar

found here:http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.2/core/security/https

Comment: If only I just read. Thanks Clyde, seems the error doesn't occur any more.